# How to init the database in fabric-ca?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I enable the fabric-ca's mysql configuration. But the fabric not init the schema. When I enroll a user, get an error `the user table not exists`. Where can I find the docs about this problem?

Here is the logs.[image]

Comment: I believe that the init script expects the database not to exist.  If it exists, then it assumes that the tables are already created.  Try deleting the database and restarting the ca-server.

Comment: @PassKit I reset the database. it failed. got a error log `Access denied for user 'xxx'@'%' to database 'fabricca'`

Comment: I had previously raised an issue regarding this (although I can't find the Jira issue) so maybe in a comment or on RocketChat.  You might need a root user or provide user to fabricca with CREATE DATABASE permissions. This may not always be possible depending on who is managing your mysql server.  If you have access to the root user - try initiating with root (this should create the database and create the tables), then manually provide permissions to the fabricca user and change your config back to that user.

Comment: @PassKit I checked the `go` source code, can not find any code to init the database.

Comment: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/blob/release/lib/dbutil/dbutil.go#L262 Function `func createMySQLTables` is only triggered if the database does not exist, and it's first step is to create database, and then tables.

Comment: BTW, in version v1.1.0-preview, the fabric-ca-server is more resilient in recovering from a bad database state like this.  Even if the database exists, it will still create any tables that don't exist.  If the table exists, it will create any entries if they don't exist, etc.